# Export/Save action customization for photoeditorsdk

Tags: photoeditorsdk

The documentation just isn't helping me figure out what to do.  I'm using Swift 4 and here is what I want to be able to do

1. When user hits the Save/Export button, save the photo to the photo
   library
2. In code, hold onto that image and pass it back to another
   view controller

I can't find in your documentation for iOS/Swift exactly how that image is held, what UIIMage or UIIMageView is pointing to it?  If you can answer with some specific code that would be very helpful.

I can't see purchasing or licensing your product without this assistance

Answer (score 0):

To do either of your points, you can register the view controller that presents the PhotoEditor SDKs `PhotoEditViewController` as the editors delegate. Afterwards, the editor will notify your view controller upon export via the `photoEditViewController(_:didSave:and:)` method described in our [docs](https://docs.photoeditorsdk.com/apidocs/ios/v8_2/Protocols/PhotoEditViewControllerDelegate.html).

The exported image is passed within the `image` argument and you can do whatever you want with it. Either save it to the iOS library or pass it around your app hierarchy.

I hope this clears things up for you!

Comment: I'm almost certain this does answer the question.  I'll give it a shot and close the issue if it works